# Eclipse Tomcat Depolyer plug in error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I downloaded [Tomcat Deployer](http://tomcatdeployer.sourceforge.net/) 
so i could deploy remotely to my tomcat server, when insert all the correct details it ask for such as:

- Manager URL
- Username/Password
- URL of sync App

when i try to deploy i keep getting this error:

```
Failed to deploy: com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianRuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Projecct [HFJSe] deploy completed.
```

And nothing is deployed.

If there anything i need to do on my Tomcat server?

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. Make sure you specified the correct manager URL, that Tomcat is running, and that you actually have the manager app installed, with correct username and password.

Comment: Errm, like i said i gave it all the correct information.. such as Manager URL
Username/Password.

Comment: Is it on same machine? If so, you may try differnt options like, IP (or)localhost(or)127.0.0.1 etc.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that the target machine is refusing the connection, so you'll need to check the following information:

- The URL is correct (I know you've stated it, but the URL should be in the format of http://{host}:{port}/TomcatHelper (from what I understand in the documentation)
- That if there is a configuation file, that the port is configured appropriately
- The target server has that port open to accepting connections
- Your username and password is correct
- If your "remote" server is on the same local machine, use your loopback address (i.e. localhost

Comment: The error randomly fixed it self, I restarted the Server and my local machine, and after restart it deployed, so i guessed it wanted a restart from the Tomcat server.